# React - Change state on item or parent?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on my first reactjs project. It's a video playlist, so this is how i structured one part of my project

```
- Component Playlist Box (just a wrapper for the playlist
-- Component Playlist (the list of video)
--- Component Video (single video)
```

Now, every time i click on a video component, it has to change its "playing" state to true and the one that is playing in that moment (if is there one) has to change its "playing" state to false.

Here is my doubt:
it is better to change the state of the clicked video component so it renders again, and change also the playing video state, or it is better to change the stat of the playlist component, so it renders every video item according to some parameter i pass to the list component? What is the best way to manage this?

Comment: Keep your state as high up as possible. If you're finding it's annoying to pass state down many components deep, use redux.

Answer (score 0):

When deciding where to store a specific state, just start with the innermost component in your hierarchy (in this case, Component Video), and ask "does this component need to know about this state?"

So does Component Video need to know about its own playing state? Absolutely. ;) What about one level up, Component Playlist? If Component Playlist is not rendering anything that cares about whether Component Video is playing or not, then just put the play state on Component Video.

Just as an example: Let's say you're rendering a blinking light on the single video component only if it's playing. But the playlist's only job is to list out single videos and doesn't concern itself whether a video is playing. In that case, it makes sense to put the state on the video component.

On the other hand, let's say the playlist rendered some text that indicated the name of the currently playing video. Then it would make sense to store the state on the playlist. E.g.:

```
class PlayList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.videoPlay = this.videoPlay.bind(this);
    this.videoStop = this.videoStop.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      playingVideoName: '',
    };
  }

  videoPlay(name) {
    this.setState({ playingVideoName: name });
  }

  videoStop() {
    this.setState({ playingVideoName: '' });
  }

  renderVideoList() {
    // begin loop
      <Video id={someId} onPlay={this.videoPlay} onStop={this.videoStop}
    // end loop
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.renderVideoList()}

      <div>
        Currently playing: {this.state.playingVideoName}
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @ffxsam your answer is clear. What i'm still confused about is how to deal with the change of the state for the old playing video. Just take your example: the playing video component is blinking, but when a new video component plays, this new one should start blinking and the old one should stop blinking. So is it the new blinking video that has to change the old video state or it is the playlist component that should manage the "blinking" state of its children component?

Comment: Right, if video 1 is playing, and suddenly you hit play on video 2, video 1 would need to stop. I'm building an app that has very similar functionality but with audio tracks. I wound up using Redux, and all the audio tracks use it to communicate with a central Web Audio API component that loads audio files from Amazon S3 and plays them.

Comment: Another way would be to have a `<PlayList>` component that has several `<Video>` components as its children. And in `PlayList`'s code, it could programatically add props to each child so it can maintain their collective state and issue commands.